# Galois-property extends across different roots?

Tags: galois-theory, galois-extensions

Suppose the extension $\mathbb{Q}(a)/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois for some root $a$ of the polynomial $f(x)$. If $b$ is another root of $f(x)$, is $\mathbb{Q}(b)/\mathbb{Q}$ also Galois? I'm thinking it should be since $\mathbb{Q}(a) \cong \mathbb{Q}(b)$

Comment: If $f$ is not irreducible in $\Bbb Q[X]$, it might not be the case. For instance, consider a non-normal extension $\Bbb Q(b)$ and $K$ the splitting field of the primitive polynomial $p_b$ of $b$ over $\Bbb Q$. By the primitive element theorem, there is some $a$ such that $K=\Bbb Q(a)$ and call $p_a$ the primitive polynomial of $a$ over $\Bbb Q$. Finally, $f=p_ap_b$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. One can use the mentioned isomorphism (isomorphism preserves normality and separability) or also observe that the assumption of normality gives $\mathbb Q(b)\subseteq \mathbb Q(a)$ while the fact that they are conjugate means they have the same degree over $\mathbb Q$, which forces equality. So not only is $\mathbb Q(b)$ also Galois, it equals $\mathbb Q(a)$.